# 'Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html' response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cross-domain

I have an ajax call to a PHP (on a different domain) login-script, which looks as the following:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://www.domain.com/PHP/fct.login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
```

And in my PHP script I have following:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'status' : '1'}" . "{'text' : 'ok'}" . "{'userid' : $member['user_id']}" . ')';
?>
```

But it doesn't work. In my console I just get a `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html` message...

**EDIT**: I updated my response as 'Felix Kling' said, but now I'm getting a parse error.

My updated response looks like:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "({status : 1},{text : 'ok'},{userid : ".$member['user_id']."})";
```

And the error looks like:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{status : 1},{text :
-^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

**EDIT 2**: Never mind, it works now (with the updated response). I just got the `parse error` when I had a direct look at the `php` script via the browser (without ajax call, etc.).

Comment: You're not retrieving javascript. Remove the `header` declaration.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Of course the response is JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling what would make you say that?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Because that's what JSONP is. Dynamically including a JavaScript file. In the OP's case, the JavaScript is invalid though. But it's still supposed to be JS.

Comment: Maybe that the browser is complaining about exactly that? (The content _was_ interpreted as script, but _send_ as something else.)

Comment: Is your problem that you  want to get `header` to work or that success callback isn't called? That might be because your generated code looks like `callbackName({'status': '1'}{'text' : 'ok})`, which is invalid JS.

Comment: Turn all PHP errors and warnings on and then look at the response and you PHP error logs. I suspect you'll have a "Cannot set headers because output already started" error in there somewhere.

Comment: the ajax call is firing my `request.fail` event (textstatus is "parseerror")

Comment: As I said, your generated code is invalid. Look at my example. You can't put multiple object literals after each other. Either you want one literal: `callback({status: 1, text: 'ok'})`, or multiple arguments, separated by comma: `callback({status: 1}, {text: 'ok'});`, although I think jQuery expects only one argument to be passed to the callback.

Comment: @FelixKling: please have a look at my updated question

Comment: @FelixKling when you make your comment as an answer than i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

The JS code you generate is incorrect. It will look like

```
callbackName({'status': '1'}{'text' : 'ok})
```

but you cannot put to object literals after each other.

Either you have to generate one literal:

```
callback({status: 1, text: 'ok'})
```

or multiple arguments, separated by commas:

```
callback({status: 1}, {text: 'ok'})
```

although I think jQuery expects only one argument to be passed to the callback.